# Robospice - addListenerIfPending - how do I know if request WAS found?

Tags: android, robospice

I am trying to implement a very simple case using robospice: a login screen. When login button is clicked, loading animation is shown and request is made using `SpiceManager.execute(..)` (without caching, of course. Since it's a login request, I need to do actual call to the server every time).

So, to handle screen rotations, etc., in `Activity.onStart()` I should use `SpiceManager.addListenerIfPending(..)`, and if request is actually pending, I should show loading animation without doing any real request.

The problem is: `PendingRequestListener` does not have `onRequestExists()` method. It only has `onRequestNotFound()`.

One possible (but unsatisfactory) solution, is to draw loading screen always, then call `addListenerIfPending(..)`, and then remove loading animation in `onRequestNotFound()`. This creates "flickering" loading screen if there was no real request, which looks really bad. What is the proper way of implementing desired behavior?

Comment: Use cache. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27136012/2440169 , it's similar problem.

Comment: Looks like a very dirty hack, which is also requires to write proper cache implementation... I will try it I guess, but I was hoping to find adequate API from Robospice, actually.

Comment: If you use predefined services from Robospice extensions (Spring, Google HTTP client, Retrofit) then cache is already implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in case google leads anyone here.
Proper solution:
in reality, this functionality is already in the library. There is a method which gets called when pending request WAS found, it just does... nothing.

You need to:

1. Create your own interface extending `PendingRequestListener`:

   ```
   public interface MyPendingRequestListener<T> extends PendingRequestListener<T> {
       void onRequestAggregated();
   }
   ```

   Note: you will need to use request listeneres implementing this interface when doing requests through Robospice.
2. Create your own class implementing `RequestListenerNotifier`. I did this by copy-pasting `DefaultRequestListenerNotifier` (I was not able to extend it because method `post(..)` is private) because it contains porper notification implementation for other cases. For example, `MyRequestListenerNotifier`.
3. Override method `notifyListenersOfRequestAggregated`:

   ```
   @Override
   public <T> void notifyListenersOfRequestAggregated(final CachedSpiceRequest<T> request, Set<RequestListener<?>> listeners) {
       post(new AggregatedRunnable(listeners), request.getRequestCacheKey());
   }

   private static class AggregatedRunnable implements Runnable {
       private final Set<RequestListener<?>> listeners;

       public AggregatedRunnable(final Set<RequestListener<?>> listeners) {
           this.listeners = listeners;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {

           if (listeners == null) {
               return;
           }

           Ln.v("Notifying " + listeners.size() + " listeners of request aggregated");
           synchronized (listeners) {
               for (final RequestListener<?> listener : listeners) {
                   if (listener != null && listener instanceof MyPendingRequestListener) {
                       Ln.v("Notifying %s", listener.getClass().getSimpleName());
                       ((MyPendingRequestListener<?>) listener).onRequestAggregated();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Extend SpiceService and override the following method (you will need to use this customized service instead of standard robospice service):

   ```
   protected RequestListenerNotifier createRequestRequestListenerNotifier() {
       return new MyRequestListenerNotifier();
   }
   ```

That's it. Now, when you use `addListenerIfPending`, `onRequestAggregated()` will be called when pending request IS found.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** This will only work when you use Cache key when doing request. For example, you can use empty string (but **NOT** null) as cache key.

Example:

```
//doing request for the first time
spiceManager.execute(request, "", DurationInMillis.ALWAYS_EXPIRED, requestListener);
//...     
//checking if request is pending e.g. when activity is restarted
spiceManager.addListenerIfPending(responseClass, "", requestListener);
```